# Unable to connect to AWS windows instance with instance type m4.large

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS Windows Instance to run a SQL Server.

I am able to select instance type as `m4.large` and start the instance.

However, I am unable to connect to it using RDP.

When I change the instance type to `m4.xlarge`, I am able to connect.

Is there a limitation on a minimum instance type required for a Windows Instance ?

Comment: Definitely not. I used to run SQL Server on t2.small or t2.medium and had no issues to RDP to it. Check that your instance actually boots up. E.g. m4.large might be not enough for either your OS or SQL Server edition you have installed, then it might crash on boot.

Comment: Agreed. Instance Type should make no difference. Be careful -- the IP address might change when an instance is stopped & started.

Comment: @Seva: It boots up fine. Even the instance checks which runs after start up shows they passed successfully. How do I find out if there was a crash on boot ?

Comment: That I don't remember unfortunately - I use Linux almost exclusively. But this should be a good starting point: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html